# FFMPEG recode SRGB image as MP4 BT.709

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a PNG file with the "sRGB IEC61966-2.1" color profile that I want to reprofile (change colors) and embed in a BT.709 MP4 file.

I can do:

```
ffmpeg -framerate 24 -i a.png -r 1/5  -c:v libx264 -s:v 1920x1080 -preset slow -pix_fmt yuv420p -vf scale=in_color_matrix=srgb:out_color_matrix=bt709 -color_primaries bt709 -color_trc bt709 -colorspace bt709 output40.mp4
```

However the colors are ~10% off. How can I fix this?

And when I replace "-vf scale=in_color_matrix=srgb:out_color_matrix=bt709" with "-vf scale=out_color_matrix=bt709" colors become more precise. Is this normal?

Comment: Can you please post a reproducible sample? Is it reproducible using using synthetic pattern `ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i testsrc=size=320x256:rate=1:duration=1 1.png`? I am getting identical files with and without `srgb:`. What is your version of FFmpeg? How do you compare the output? Can you post your input image, and the output images (frames)?

Comment: @Rotem I have been using the screenshot tool unfortunately. Could you please suggest a good way of extracting rgb from an mp4 file? I'm working with a single colored rectangle filling the entire screen

Comment: You can use FFmpeg for converting mp4 file to sequence of PNG image files. Using a video player is fine, but there is a chance of a bug in the video player. If your are using a Mac, there could be other issues (I think). For single color PNG, you may use a command like: `ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i color=0x3355AA:size=320x256:rate=1:duration=1 1.png`

Comment: You were right; the video player doesn't handle colors well. I'll accept your last comment as the correct answer if you can post it so.

Comment: No, this is not an answer. I was just trying to convince you to improve the question. This is also not a programming question, and better fit Super User site.